# How to get count of all Events associated with same Opportunity

Tags: apex, soql, event

There are six Events created for Opportunity 'ABC' with the same Subject name and I need to count all these Events based on Status field.

I am using the below query for fetching the Events but it returns only one Event. The first event was created in 2018 and four events in 2019 and one in 2020, the query returns the event which is created in 2020.

"SELECT Id,(SELECT Id,Event_Status__c FROM Events) FROM opportunity where id='xxxxxxxxxx'"

How I can count all these events by using apex, please suggest. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this your original query? This query is straight forward which should return all of your event irrespective of Event Status or Subject

Comment: Yes, In spite of removing status filter it only returns one event of this year

Comment: Even, "select id from Event where WhatId ='oppid' this query returns only one record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your activities are archived. See [Work with Archived Activities](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=activities_archived.htm&type=5) and [Archived Activities](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_guidelines_archive.htm) in the SOAP API reference for more details.

Regular queries do not include archived activities. In SOQL, you can query for archived activities by including the [`ALL ROWS`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_query_all_rows.htm) clause.

> SOQL statements can use the ALL ROWS keywords to query all records in an organization, including deleted records and archived activities. For example:

Comment: Thank you So much, David, for your help. By using "SELECT Id FROM Event WHERE WHATID = 'xxxxx' AND isDeleted = FALSE ALL ROWS"  this query gives the count but it gives one extra count means there are six visible events under activity but got count seven please clarify.

Comment: I can't see your data,  @jsmith; I'm not sure how to answer that question

Comment: Thanks a lot, David!